# Github, finding most updated forks

Tags: github, fork

I remember there was a page on Github where you could see a list of all forks with an horizontal bar chart showing how it did stack against the original, comparing the last commit.
I can't find it anymore, was it removed?
It was useful for project abandoned that were maybe picked up by someone, it was quite obvious from the chart .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Insights tab, and then click on Network in the sidebar on the left.

[image: Screenshot showing GitHub interface after clicking the "Insights" tab, followed by clicking "Network" in the sidebar on the left]

This feature can be a bit hard to find.

Comment: Thanks! That's it. It has been a long time since I needed it and it's really hidden!

Comment: @ChristianBrandoni no worries! Please don't forget to upvote and mark this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the answer. This will also help other users know that the question was answered.

Comment: Thanks, of course. It wouldn't let me accept the answer until now, there was a countdown. I can't upvote sorry, not enough reputation.